# sed-remove all but last occurrence of a character from a line

Tags: sed

Suppose I have some lines like

```
author = {Bill Catsman},
title = {{Hello} {{Cruel} {World}}}
```

and I want to remove all but the first and last brackets from `title`. I can do `sed -r 's/title\ \=\ \{//2g'` to get rid of the extra `{`s, but how can I get rid of the extra `}`s?

Desired output is

```
author = {Bill Catsman}, 
title = {Hello Cruel World}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove all occurrences of `{` or `}` as long as they are **inside** another `{...}`:

```
$ sed -E ':a; s/(\{.*)[{}](.*\})/\1\2/; ta' file
author = {Bill Catsman},
title = {Hello Cruel World}
```

This has the effect of keeping only the outer curly braces.

How it works:

- `:a`

  This defines a label `a`.
- `s/(\{.*)[{}](.*\})/\1\2/`

  This looks for any curl braces that are inside another set of curly braces and removes them.
- `ta`

  If the last *substitute* command made a change to the line, then jump to label `a` and try again.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks for the answer and clear explanation!